# App store upload and setting deployment target in iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, app-store, distribution

i have built my app using xcode 4, & its working fine on ios 3.1.3 device if i set my deployment target to 3.1.3 , it is working fine ios 4 and if i set the deployment target to 4 ,my doubt is while uploading to app store what deployment target should i set?????

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES and NO.

YES: Because it will run on iOS 3.1.3 for the APIs and methods supported till 3.1.3

NO: Because it will not support the APIs introduced in iOS versions > 3.1.3

Example: If you integrate SMS functionality as it was introduced in iOS 4.0

Comment: i have built my app using xcode 4, & its working fine on ios 3.1.3 device if i set my deployment target to 3.1.3 , it is working fine ios 4 and if i set the deployment target to 4 ,my doubt is while uploading to app store what deployment target should i set?????

Comment: Ideally you should support the minimum iOS version in order that everybody can use your app.So i would suggest you should set deployment target as minimum as possible which suites your functionality in app

Comment: if i set it to 3.1.3 (i.e minimum ) , will it work on ios 4 devices

Comment: Yes of course it will work on iOS4 devices,have you not checked it by doing so...